# Reading Custom XML File

Tags: c#, xml

This is Guardian.re, which is a custom XML file that I've createed in C#. I have created a new program that I want to read this file and place the info in a listbox. The xmlns being the name of the user that was entered. How do I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is the Guardian Submit file. An admin will read with their viewers.-->
<Guardian 
    Age="5" 
    Hours="5" 
    Why="Why?" 
    Qualify="What qualifies you?" 
    xmlns="Name" />
```

Here is the C# source:

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists("Guardian.re") == false)
            {
                //.re is the file extension that is used

                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"Guardian.re");

                writer.WriteStartDocument();

                writer.WriteComment("This is the Guardian Submit file. An admin will read with their viewers.");
                //Element <Guardian> in the .re XML format
                writer.WriteStartElement("Guardian", IGN);



                //the element <Age> in the .re XML format
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Age", Age);

                //the element <Hours> in the .re XML format
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Hours", hours);

                //the element <Why> in the .re XML format
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Why", WhyRank);

                //the element <Qualify> in the .re XML format
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Qualify", Qualify);
                writer.WriteEndElement();



                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: What will be the values and keys of the list items?

Comment: Name:  Age:  Hours: Why: Qualifications:  (Each of these are a new item on the listbox)

Comment: If you use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx) would have been much easier!!

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath to get your individual values back from the file as found here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

and then add the values to the listbox as specified here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288403(v=vs.71).aspx

You can also find some code here [Parse XML and populate in List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805477/parse-xml-and-populate-in-list-box)

Answer (score 0):

I posted a possible answer for this here: [Reading an XML File With Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668413/reading-an-xml-file-with-linq/20669837#20669837) 
Guess I probably should have waited, as the other is in regards to Linq...